# Autocomplete Ruby on Rails form_for using HTML5 Datalist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, autocomplete

I have a form with text field:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name, "First Name" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

How do I use the HTML5 Datalist element to autocomplete the text field?

Answer (score 9):

This works for me on Rails 4.2beta.

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name, "First Name" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, list: "names" %>
  <datalist id="names">
    <option value="Kalle">
    <option value="Jarmo">
    <option value="Pekka">
  </datalist>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```